# How can "find" optimize successive runs?

Tags: bash

I noticed that only the first calls to `find` require a lot of time (and multiple accesses to the hard drive, since it produces noise), meanwhile the successive ones are optimized.

How can the command `find` do that?

I see the same behaviour on `bash` and `fish`. Same behaviour on `ext4` and `ntfs` (even though I performed the >1mil files test only on `ntfs`)

e.g.

```sh
# on SSD
$ time find . -type f -name "*.m"| wc -l
33

real    0m1,189s
user    0m0,090s
sys     0m0,295s

$ time find . -type f -name "*.m"| wc -l
33

real    0m0,203s
user    0m0,053s
sys     0m0,149s
```

```sh
# on SSD
time find . -type f -name "*.java"| wc -l
547

real    0m11,982s
user    0m1,645s
sys     0m1,012s

$ time find . -type f -name "*.java"| wc -l
547

real    0m4,184s
user    0m1,581s
sys     0m0,970s
```

In a folder with more that 3mil files the time required goes from 1-2 minutes to:

```sh
# on HD
$ time find . -type f | wc -l
3746258

real    0m2,778s
user    0m0,753s
sys     0m1,037s
```

Comment: [Find/ls caching - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78726/117037)

Comment: ["find" command and linux cache  - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1806925)

Comment: The files don't fit in memory. The directories' inodes do. It's all metadata.

Comment: I see! Thank you for your reply